# Check role membership against Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, rbac

I am implementing a server to server RBAC with AAD by leveraging the new Microsoft Graph (Rest) API.
I can successfully authenticate and check user group membership based on the [checkMemberGroups resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-checkmembergroups?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

I am trying to take this to the next level- instead of checking group membership I want to check the Role of a user. The role is defined based on [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps#:%7E:text=Under%20Manage%2C%20select%20App%20registrations,the%20settings%20for%20the%20role).

I created the role, assigned it to a user and then attempted to check role assignment using the [checkMemberObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-checkmemberobjects?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) API:

> Check for membership in a list of group or directory roles for the specified user object.

This did not work; I passed the role id to the API but the response contained an empty array- suggesting that the assignment did not take place.

However, when I tried listing the Role Assignments for the user using [appRoleAssignments resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), I did indeed see the id of the role there.

My question: am I using the checkMemberObjects inappropriately (am I mixing different domains here)? If so-
What is the correct way to check whether a user has a certain role?

I am using rest API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[checkMemberObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-checkmemberobjects?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) is used to check if the user is in a group. It's not getting if it has an app role.

I'm afraid there is not an Microsoft Graph endpoint which checks if the user has a certain app role.

But you can use [List appRoleAssignments granted to a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to check it as a workaround.

List all the app role assignments and check if the certain app role id is included in the response using `contains()` or `IndexOf()`and so on.

Comment: Thanks Allen. The checkMemberObjects distinctly states that it covers roles as well as groups, unlike checkMemberGroups which _is_ only for groups. So what am I missing?

Comment: @Vitaliy The roles it mentioned is referring to AAD role rather than app role. For example: global admin, application admin.

Comment: Right...I wonder why they didn't roll out a similar API. Isn't checking role assignment a common pattern?

Comment: @Vitaliy I agree with you. I believe more and more common patterns would be supported in the future. If you have any good idea, pls post it on [Microsoft Graph User Voice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests]).

Comment: [Just did](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/42644710-add-an-api-to-check-for-role-membership)